# Where does Spring Boot define its default JSON date (i.e. LocalDateTime) format?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

When creating a REST service with Spring Boot that returns a JSON payload, Java 8's `LocalDateTime` gets serialized. Where is the format string (i.e. the pattern) defined that (presumably) Jackson applies when marshalling the object to a string, and where can I find the default configuration in Spring Boot that applies that format (i.e. sets the formater)?

(NB: I can see a formatted date, not a timestamp, in the payload.)

Comment: A LocalDateTime is not a timestamp, so it's quite normal that you don't see a timestamp. That said, the documentation answers your question: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: The docs point me to [`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#460), which in turn points to [`JSR310Module`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.4.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JSR310Module.java#129) and via...

Comment: ...[`LocalDateTimeSerializer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.4.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/LocalDateTimeSerializer.java#69) finally to [`LocalDateTime::toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/time/LocalDateTime.java#1965). My `LocalDateTime` is set to `1776-07-04T12:29Z`, yet I get `1776-07-04T12:29:00Z`. Docs say "The format used will be the shortest ... where the omitted parts are implied to be zero": `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm`. Why do I get `:00` back?

Comment: LocalDateTime doesn't have a timezone. So you can't have such a final Z. If you have, you probably are not actually serializing a LocalDateTime. `System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("1776-07-04T12:29"));` produces the output you expect: 1776-07-04T12:29

Answer (score 0):

`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` performs pretty tricky logic in `registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable` method for registering several modules. In particular for java 8 time:

```
// Java 8 java.time package present?
if (ClassUtils.isPresent("java.time.LocalDate", this.moduleClassLoader)) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Module> javaTimeModule = (Class<? extends Module>)
                ClassUtils.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule", this.moduleClassLoader);
        objectMapper.registerModule(BeanUtils.instantiateClass(javaTimeModule));
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // jackson-datatype-jsr310 not available
    }
}
```

So if your application depends on `jackson-datatype-jsr310` module spring will silently register it. As the result you will have dedicated serializers/deserializers for java time types from this module. You are interesting in [`LocalDateTimeSerializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/LocalDateTimeSerializer.java). As you can see serialization logic depends on `useTimestamp` which in your case returns false, so we move to `else` branch. By default `_formatter` is null and `_defaultFormatter()` is used which is [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). You can easily update this behavior by providing a custom formatter if you want to serialize date as string or use serialization logic from `if` branch by returning `true` from `useTimestamp` method.

```
@Override
public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider)
    throws IOException
{
    if (useTimestamp(provider)) {
        g.writeStartArray();
        g.writeNumber(value.getYear());
        g.writeNumber(value.getMonthValue());
        g.writeNumber(value.getDayOfMonth());
        g.writeNumber(value.getHour());
        g.writeNumber(value.getMinute());
        if (value.getSecond() > 0 || value.getNano() > 0) {
            g.writeNumber(value.getSecond());
            if(value.getNano() > 0) {
                if (provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS))
                    g.writeNumber(value.getNano());
                else
                    g.writeNumber(value.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
            }
        }
        g.writeEndArray();
    } else {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = _formatter;
        if (dtf == null) {
            dtf = _defaultFormatter();
        }
        g.writeString(value.format(dtf));
    }
}

// since 2.7: TODO in 2.8; change to use per-type defaulting
protected DateTimeFormatter _defaultFormatter() {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
}

protected boolean useTimestamp(SerializerProvider provider) {
    if (_useTimestamp != null) {
        return _useTimestamp.booleanValue();
    }
    // assume that explicit formatter definition implies use of textual format
    if (_formatter != null) { 
        return false;
    }
    return provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
}
```